# Non-science according to Popper's Criterion for Demarcation

Tags: popper, classification

So, Popper's Criterion for Demarcation goes something like this: “statements or systems of statements, in order to be ranked as scientific, must be capable of conflicting with possible, or conceivable observations”.

But what about all the rest, the non-science? No further, finer demarcation for the non-science?

If we can't distinguish between

> Every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root.

and

> Young girls experience anxiety upon realization that they do not have a penis – penis envy. The penis envy stage begins the transition from an attachment to the mother to competition with the mother for the attention, recognition and affection of the father.

what's the big deal about the Criterion for Demarcation?

Non-science (applying the Criterion) can be *completely* crazy or can constitute the most rigorous and well-established knowledge.

Comment: See [Popper and The Problem of Demarcation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/popper/#ProbDema) and [Science and Pseudo-Science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pseudo-science/) : "The phrases “demarcation of science” and “demarcation of science from pseudoscience” are often used interchangeably, and many authors seem to have regarded them as equal in meaning. This picture is oversimplified. All non-science is not pseudoscience, and science has non-trivial borders to other non-scientific phenomena, such as metaphysics, religion, and various types of non-scientific systematized knowledge."

Comment: Popper's criteria is aimed at clarifuing the status od so-called "empirical sciences". Thus, the non-applicability of the citeria to logic and mathematics does not mean that they are "pseudo-sciences".

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) "*The falsifiability criterion does not imply that unfalsifiable systems such as logic, mathematics and metaphysics are not parts of science*", and quotes Thornton:"*For Popper, however, to assert that a theory is unscientific, is not necessarily to hold that it is unenlightening, still less that it is meaningless*", indeed, he originally classified evolution theory as a "metaphysical programme". I wonder what it genrally takes to become part of science despite being unfalsifiable.